# View outlook calendar in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

Is it possible to view outlook calendar in SharePoint 2013?

Head of the department wants to view everyone's Outlook Calendar in the SharePoint 2013. Is this possible?

He can view other's outlook calendar in his outlook a/c but he wants to view other's outlook calendar in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In a SharePoint calendar, in the ribbon, on the Calendar tab, click Calendar Overlays.
2. In the Calendar Overlay Settings page, click New Calendar.
3. In the Name and Type section, type the Calendar Name and select Exchange.
4. In the Calendar Overlay Settings section, type a Description for the calendar (optional), and change the default Color theme for the calendar (optional).
5. Screenshot of the Calendar Overlay dialog box in SharePoint. The dialog box shows the Calendar name, calendar type (Exchange), and gives the URLs for Outlook Web Access and Exchange Web Access.
6. Click Find to automatically fill in web addresses for Outlook Web Access URL and Exchange Web Service URL. If Find does not work in your environment, type the URLs manually.
   If you want this Exchange calendar to always appear with the SharePoint group calendar, select Always Show.
7. Click OK and then click OK again.

[image]

Comment: After setting up URLs i am getting this error message The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic Realm=""'. (eeb15a9c-a837-0071-76c4-f39e4c4f501d)

Comment: I am working with SharePoint 2013 and Outlook 2010. We notice that although we have a valid OWA url .. the calendar seems to default to personal calendar .. not the one team cal we want.

Answer (score -1):

Its possible integrate outlook to calendar list in SharePoint

1. Go to the calendar, library, or list that you want to connect to Outlook.
2. Click Calendar, Library, or List. (The name of the tab varies depending on which type of list or library you are connecting to Outlook.)
3. Click Connect to Outlook.

   NOTE    In a tasks list, the name of the command appears as Sync to Outlook, and does additional synchronization of your tasks between SharePoint and Outlook.
4. In the dialog boxes that appear click Allow or Yes as appropriate. If your site is a part of an Office365 subscription, you may be required to use your subscription user name and password.

See this [Article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-small-business-help/synchronize-sharepoint-content-with-outlook-HA102774420.aspx)

Comment: Please try to not only provide a link as an answer, try adding the best bits from the link to you post :)

Comment: its simple and work, I used this link. You can connect outlook of a user with list, you must create a list foreach user

Comment: Still, add the important part to your post. If the link breaks your post will be of no help to future readers if you catch my drift :)

Comment: Sorry, I understand you drift

Comment: Now I have done it for you.

Comment: i need to do other way around. I can see sharepoint calendar in outlook but i want to see outlook calendar in sharepoint.

Comment: This is connecting Sharepoint to Outlook, not Outlook into Sharepoint.