# Connect Exchange 2013 Calendar to SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-calendar, exchange

I've managed to create a calendar overlay to present a domain user's calendar in SP 2013 but all appointments are showing as Busy/Out of Office/Tentative etc.

I have followed the blog posts below and the calendar already has the show Full Details selected.

[View outlook calendar in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83366/view-outlook-calendar-in-sharepoint-2013)

http://blogs.technet.com/b/ptsblog/archive/2011/05/31/sharepoint-and-exchange-calendar-together.aspx

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overlay-a-SharePoint-calendar-with-a-calendar-from-Exchange-or-SharePoint-4caebe59-3994-4a94-9322-b31abb8a5e9a

Is there anything else I could check please?  I have given the domain 'Everyone' group Read access to the shared mailbox as it's not sensitive but it still hasn't changed the calendar entries.

Any help is appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0):

Calendar Overlay show the event time and the status i.e **Busy, Free, In Meeting** etc not the actual event detail i.e **Meeting with Boss**, **Annual Dinner** etc. Only one's own exchange calendar will be visible to him after login into SharePoint. No one else can see other's calendar.

You can write some custom code to query the exchange server with any valid login ID to get Calendar events. You can use impersonation in code and then can query anyone's exchange Calendar. For implementing impersonation, you would need a service account that would have read access on all exchange calendars. Below is a sample web part that fetches emails from exchange by implementing impersonation. You can modify the code according to your requirements.

https://exchangewp.codeplex.com/

Hope it helps.